# How in donut chart element of leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts to set custom color for any category?

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

Using donut chart element of leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts in filament admin site and looking at examples at
https://github.com/leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts site
if there is a way a) set set custom color for any category ? b) show also value with percent in data series ?

```
"filament/filament": "^2.17.21",
"filament/forms": "^2.17.21",
"laravel/framework": "^9.52.5",
"leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts": "^1.0.2",
"livewire/livewire": "^2.12.3",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This package is an Filament integration of Apex Charts. [Here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/pie-donut/) you can see how to show values as percentages. Basically,

```
options = {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function (val) {
      return val + "%"
    },
    dropShadow: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

and for the colors, see documentation [here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/)

> Colors for the chart’s series. When all colors of the array are used,
> it starts from the beginning

```
{
  colors: ['#546E7A', '#E91E63'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your link!
I managet to set custom color for for any category with data.
But actuall leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts is a php wrapper for javascript library .
I do not see in which way I can use formatter method in my php getOptions(): array function ?
Some custom javascript code on eandrocfe/filament-apex-charts side? I do not see such functionality...